# AWS Cognito Pre Sign Up trigger not running for Hosted UI Google Auth needed to add birth date attribute

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to Use Google Oauth in a React Native application however I originally set birthdate as a required field in cognito which even after requesting https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read as an attribute from google, my sign in requests are failing.

```
console.error: [ERROR] 27:06.825 OAuth - Error handling auth response. Error: attributes+required%3A+%5Bbirthdate%5D
```

I was recommended to just use a pre sign up lambda trigger to add a pre configured birthdate field in so that I can sign up however the lambda doesn't appear to be used as it doesn't generate any cloudwatch logs from federated sign in calls.

I'm just using `Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Google'})` to sign in and the hosted ui page is working fine.

Is there a reason this sign in request isn't reaching the pre sign up trigger? Is there an alternative here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to map the attribute from the Social Provider to your User Pool.

User Pool > Federation > Attribute Mapping. Capture Birthdate and map it to the user pool attribute.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not being an answer at all.